# Exclude featured image from gallery in wp-admin

Tags: images, wp-admin, post-thumbnails, gallery

Is there a way to prevent the featured image from even showing up in a post's gallery?

e.g. when editing the gallery in the admin for a post, the featured image isn't there.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by that? Are you talking about the title?

Comment: Ah, my failure. I had several tabs open and was reviewing questions. Seems like I mixed up the questions and added the comment to the wrong question.

Comment: Haha that's okay!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I had the same problem and just solved it by adding an "exclude" field to the shortcode. Like so...

```
[gallery link="file" columns="4" orderby="title" exclude="1050"]
```

You have to just pull the ID number of the file you don't want to show. This works without adding any functions or edits to the theme.

Answer (score 1):

I am agree with @janw's answer.

I would like to add further as:

You can edit your single template to automatically show the gallery without needing to insert the gallery shortcode manually.
Open your single.php file and inside the loop, where you want the gallery to be displayed, copy this line of code:

```
<?php  $id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()); // gets the post thumbnail ID ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode("[gallery exclude={$id}]"); // insert the gallery without the thumbnail ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [`gallery` shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) you can add the `exclude` param with the id of the featured image to exclude it.

If you want to do it dynamically I suggest using the [`post_gallery`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/post_gallery) filter.

```
<?php // add to functions.php
add_filter ('post_galley', 'exclude_featured_img');
function exclude_featured_img($attr)
{
    if (!isset($attr['exclude']) || empty($attr['exclude'])) {
        return $attr['exclude'] = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    } else {
        return $attr['exclude'] = $attr['exclude'] . ',' . get_post_thumbnail_id();
    }
}
```

not tested but should work.

Comment: I am trying to do this same thing and the code did not work. The featured image is still sitting in the middle of the gallery.

Comment: Actually this will not work, as the `post_galley` is intended to filter the entire output of the `[gallery]` shortcode, not the `$atts` passed. So if you `return '<div>'` in `exclude_featured_img` function for example, the `[gallery]` shortcode will print `<div>` on the screen. In order to use this filter correctly, you have to re-write the entire output of the `gallery` shortcode while specifying the `exclude` argument. See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40988/how-to-filter-post-gallery-after-all-other-filters-plugins-etc) for more details.